# Flutter/Material Design: How to add "quick search buttons"

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget, material-design

I'm trying to add "quick search buttons" to my flutter app like (in red):

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a material design component - if it is, I was hoping to identify the name so that I can e.g. search https://pub.dev/ for an existing widget.

1. **Does anyone know what this material design component is called (if applicable)?**
2. **How can I implement it/does an existing widget exist on e.g. https://pub.dev/?**

Many thanks! :)

Comment: You can use flutter builtin widget ```Chip``` or you can build your own customized widget using a ```Container``` and a ```borderRadius``` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `FilterChip` widget for implementing "quick search buttons"
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html

or you can also create your custom widget for achieving this UI

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyFilterChip extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFilterChip({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyFilterChip> createState() => _MyFilterChipState();
}

class _MyFilterChipState extends State<MyFilterChip> {
  List fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'papaya', 'orange', 'guava'];
  int selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 30,
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: fruits.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => FilterChip(
                  label: Text(fruits[index]),
                  selected: index == selectedIndex,
                  onSelected: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are called chips, refer to this page https://material.io/components/chips. There is also a section of how to implement these in flutter.